# Json Structure- How to read this JSON structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Can anyone help me to fetch the comments value from the below json structure. 
Actually i want the id(very first column after items) for which the no of comments is 0. I m able to read the id but unable to put the  if condition (comment =0) return {id}

```
            "data": {
             "posts": {
              "items": [
            {
                "id": ,

                "content": {
                    "id": ,

                    "files": [],
                    "user_details": {
                        "firstname": "",
                        "lastname": ""

                    },
                    "comments": "",
                    "tags": [
                        "anonymous"
                    ],
                    "likeCount": 0,
                    "group_details": {
                        "group_name": "",
                        "guid": 
                    },
                    "propertytags": {
                        "empty": ""
                    },
                    "permalink": {
                        "link": 
                    },
                    "isFollowed": ,
                    "followerCount": "",
                    "favorite": "",
                    "isLiked": ""
                },
                "contentType": "",
                "group_details": {
                    "group_name": ,
                    "guid": 
                }
            }
```

How to read comments value?????

Comment: `data.posts.items[index].content.comments`

Answer (score 0):

`data.posts.items[index].content.comments` will give you the value of comments. 
However to fetch the id based on comment value, you may use `Array.filter()` function.

```
let result = data.posts.items.filter(item => {
    if (item.content.comments === "0") {
        return item.id;
    }
});
```

`result` will be an array of `id` for which the `comments` is `0`.

Here is an example with the data you've shared [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/bageloqeta/edit?js,console)